# How many ways to choose elements from three groups then permutate them

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A,B,C$ be three disjoint sets with $|A| = a, |B|=b,|C|=c$ elements.
You choose $k_1 \leq a$ elements from set $A$, $k_2 \leq b$ elements from set $B$ and $k_3 \leq c$ elements from set $C$ (repetition is allowed).
On how many ways can you permutate these $k_1+k_2+k_3$ chosen elements?

To choose the elements I would say you have $a^{k_1},b^{k_2},c^{k_3}$ options each.
If repetition wasn't allowed, the answer would be $(k_1+k_2+k_3)!$. But with repetition you also have to consider the cases where one, two or more elements from e.g. set $A$ were chosen twice or even more and exclude them from the permutation.

Is there a formula or efficient way which considers all the possibilities of double counting?

Comment: Before you can address the permutation question, are $A,B,C$ disjoint?  Otherwise you could have repetition of elements between them which further complicates permuting

Comment: Yes, they are. Also, I think that instead of $a^{k_1}$ the amount is $\binom{a+k_1-1}{k_1}$ since I already consider the order with the faculty.

Comment: I think I figured it out. It is $a^{k_1}\cdot b^{k_2}\cdot c^{k_3} \dfrac{(k_1 + k_2+k_3)!}{k_1 ! \cdot k_2 ! \cdot k_3 !}$ since you permute only the order of elements of different sets.